Adapter static doesn't properly crawl links in svelte components
Error: The following routes were marked as prerenderable, but were not prerendered because they were not found while crawling your app:
  - /changelog

I got this error and running build with my adapter-static failed, even though I have a link to changelog:
<a href="/changelog">changelog</a>
in my component inside a modal.
When I add the same line:
<a href="/changelog">changelog</a>
inside my homepage (+page.svelte), then it does not show the above error and successfully prerenders /changelog.
When I fork https://node.new/sveltekit and remove the /about link and add adapter-static and run build, it seems to run fine without errors, so it must be a project specific problem. But I've confirmed it's resolved by simply pasting in <a href="/changelog">changelog</a> into my file.
Thanks in advance!

I should note that I can just list /changelog in my config, but this shouldn't be necessary. Is this a bug in svelte kit's auto adapter or am I doing something wrong?

In their example svelte kit project, they only link to /about from the  component which is also a svelte component and it renders fine with adapter static

My understanding is now that the auto crawler doesn't crawl the source code, it crawls the website like a search engine, starting from index.html.
So if my changelog link is in a modal, then it would never renders and then it never crawls the link. It seems like this isn't a bug, but just how the crawler operates. Solution is to add to svelte.config.js under config.kit.prerender.entries which is an array of relative urls, and contains '/changelog' now as well.

You are right, SvelteKit will look at the pre-rendered HTML code and only follow the links there. The proper solution is that your Show Modal button is a link that changes the URL, so the modal really is a separate page. Then search engines can also crawl your modals, and users can bookmark them, etc.
